# How to return a variable from a Q Node promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongoose, q

I have a learning game using Angular, Express, Mongo and Node. I'm now learning how to use promises, so I can wait until something is finished before starting something else.

Right now, I'm trying to wait until the database says if the user trying to login already have an account. I've succeeded with that, so if the user does not exist, the `.then()` will call the `onReject` function that will create the user.

The `user` have a master account and can play sessions. Within each session, he will receive a new `player`. If the `user` exist and tries to login and his `player` is logged, he will receive that `player` back. If the `player` does not exist, the server will create one for him.

But, I'm having a problem with the variable `logged`, that says if the user have a logged `player`. On the second line of the function `findUser`, I'm creating a variable called `logged` and I'm trying to return it, so I can use on the `onResolve` function.

```
UserModel.find(
            { username: username, password: password},
            findUser ).then( 
             onResolve,
             onReject     );
```

**On Promise resolve**

```
      var onResolve = function (logged) {

          if (logged) { 
             //RETURN USER'S PLAYER
          } else {
             //CREATE USER'S PLAYER
          }

       }
```

**On Promise reject**

```
        var onReject = function () {
            userModel.save( function (err) {
                if (!err) {
                    //CREATE USER
                    //CREATE USER'S PLAYER
                }
            });
        });
```

**Function findUser**

```
var findUser = function (err, data) {
    var logged = false;
    var userSearched = Q.defer();
    if (data.length) { //IF USER IS IN DATABASE
        logged = true;
        userSearched.resolve(logged);
    } else {
        userSearched.reject(logged);
    }

    return userSearched.promise;
};
```

How could I return the `logged` variable from the promise to use anywhere I need?

Comment: You can't return `logged` to outside the promise. Instead, return the promise and use it anywhere you need `logged`.

Comment: I'm returning userSearched.promise. How do I access logged value from there?

Comment: see jfriend00's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you return a value from a `.then()` handler, then that value becomes the fulfilled value of the promise.

```
 var onResolve = function (logged) {

      if (logged) { 
         //RETURN USER'S PLAYER
      } else {
         //CREATE USER'S PLAYER
      }
      // ** add this **
      return logged;
   }
```

You can then use it in subsequent `.then()` handlers:

```
UserModel.find({ username: username, password: password}, findUser)
   .then( onResolve, onReject)
   .then(function(result) {
        // can access result here
    });
```

---

If this code is inside a function, then you can return the promise from `UserModel.find()`:

```
function someFunc() {
    return UserModel.find({ username: username, password: password}, findUser)
       .then( onResolve, onReject);

}
```

And, then add a `.then()` handler to the returned promise.

```
someFunc().then(function(result) {
   // access result here
});
```

---

Or, in your `findUser()` function:

```
var findUser = function (err, data) {
    var userSearched = Q.defer();
    if (data.length) { //IF USER IS IN DATABASE
        userSearched.resolve(true);
    } else {
        userSearched.reject(false);
    }

    return userSearched.promise;
};

findUser.then(function(val) {
    // access resolved value here
}, function(err) {
    // access rejected reason here
});
```

Though, `findUser()` does not look asynchronous so I don't really understand why you're using a promise with it at all.  It appears you can just return `true` or `false` from the function directly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick and complete answer. I'm trying it. ;)